# Avoid collision in importing data in R

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o, import-from-csv, sklearn-pandas

I faced an error trying to import a CSV into R which had multiple duplicate columns, is there a way I can ignore those columns?
It's easy to do that in case of small files and small number of columns but mine is a big one ~3k columns and 10M rows.

Comment: What code were you running exactly and what was the exact error you are getting? I wouldn't think there's a problem reading a file even if it does have duplicate columns.

Comment: readr::read_csv and data.table::fread are both big improvements over read.csv and read.table in base.  Perhaps try them if the base functions are giving you sorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, set the check.names arg to FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Read in the first row, I.e. the column headers, with readLines. strsplit to parse to vector. Rename duplicated elements. Then you can call read.csv with a col.names arg.